# Enviar por correo varios archivos adjuntos laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, gmail, mail

Hice este código pero solo me envia un archivo adjunto al correo y no los "x" archivos que selecciono, intente hacer un array y un foreach pero no me da resultado, ¿alguien podría ayudarme para que me mande todos los arcchivos que selecciono a mi correo?

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.mensaje-recibido')->attach($this->msg['archivo']->getRealPath(),['as'=>$this->msg['archivo']->getClientOriginalName()]);



boton
 <input class="form-control bg -light shadow-sm @error('content') is-invalid @elseborder-0 @enderror " type="file" id="archivo"  name="archivo"  required multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es guardar el email generado en una variable y luego iterar sobre los archivos que quieras adjuntar. Algo asi:

```
$email = $this->view('emails.mensaje-recibido');

foreach($this->msg['archivo'] as $attachment){
  $email->attach(
    $attachment->getRealPath(),
    ['as'=> $attachment->getClientOriginalName()]
  );
}

return $email;
```